# running basic loops on browser console returns undefined but it works on online editors

Tags: loops

[here you can see on chrome browser it returns undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ddG.png)
[however on this random compiler, it works just fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCgz1.png)

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

I just wanted to get a better understanding of the different loops in javascript, mainly forEach and since i (thought) i already understood for and while loops, i'd use them to help me understand forEach loops however when i ran my while and for loops, i got this result instead.

Comment: Works as expected for me ...

Comment: yeah it works fine now, i still dont know what the problem was...